# Automator app for tar-gzip (or pigz)

Tags: bash, gzip, tar, automator

I'm trying to make an 'Archive Utility' replacement under OSX to open tar.gz files with tar and gzip (or pigz) commands.

The point is to make an app in Automator so i can bind tar.gz filetype to it, then, when a tar.gz file is clicked, a shell script expands the file using pigz/tar/gzip/etc instead of the default archive utility.

My app consists of a 'Run Shell Script' (or a Get Selected Finder Items -> Run Shell Script, i've tried both) which executes:

```
/usr/local/bin/pigz -dc "$1" | tar xf -
```

The inputs are being passed as arguments, but for some reason, it's not working.

When used from the commandline, it works perfect, but when set as an app, it does nothing.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#!/bin/bash
pigz -dc "$1" | tar xf - -C "$(dirname "$1")"
```

or use `notify-send` or whatever notifier's available on OSX to debug the script.

On Linux, the unmodified script, when run in a file-browser from a non-home directory extracted into `$HOME` because `$PWD` was always `$HOME` (as I learned from `notify-send`) no matter where in the file-browser I was. Hence the fix to use the directory of the argument.

Your problem might be elsewhere. At the very least you need to make sure your script is executable and in your `$PATH` (your `$PATH` as seen by your GUI). As an alternative to using a notifier, you can dump some info into a file and `tail -f` that file from a terminal as you invoke the script from your GUI.